# Qt5 - How to pass a `QList<T> *` pointer as signal parameter and have it deleted when finished?

Tags: c++, qt5, signals, delete-operator

I would like to pass a QList as a signal parameter in Qt5 .

The following code suggests the idea, but the problem is with the QList object that should be deleted after the signal was sent to all listeners.

```cpp
class SomeClass {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
Q_SIGNALS:
    void dataReceived(QList<T> *list);
private:
    void someFunction(void);
}

void SomeClass::someFunction(void) {
    QList<T> *list=new QList<T>();
    /* ... fill list*/
    emit dataReceived(list);
}
```

How should I do this to pass the `QList` and have it properly deleted when the signal has been handled by all slots?

EDIT:

Given the discussion int the comment of the suggestion to use a "shared_ptr", I did the following which results in a segmentation fault.  So I'll need to dig into shared_ptr a bit more .

```cpp
    std::shared_ptr<QList<T>> list;
    /* segmentation fault on next line */
    list.get()->append({ item });
```

EDIT:
- I also consider cross-thread signaling which may interfere with the lifetime of data.

Comment: Use `std::allocator` to allocate and de-allocate whenever you want. Or even `unique_ptr` if you want a safe, dynamic, and auto-destructive pointer or array.

Comment: I would use `void dataReceived(const QList<t> &list)` instead of a pointer. Then there is no need to create a new object, nor to delete it.

Comment: @soopchanov I have doubts about that as list is created in the sender and list likely crosses to another thread.

Comment: @Ie_top, check the example in my answer. You might as well adapt it for a multi-thread scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should pass `shared_ptr` instead of raw pointer.

Comment: Maybe, but I have no experience with it - is it safe in this context ?  Should I just write "shared_ptr<QList<T>> sharedVar".  Is sharedVar a pointer?  Is sharedVare also a `QList<T>`?

Comment: Yes, you should use`shared_ptr<QList<T>>` in my opinion. That creates a shared pointer that is a class with overloaded `->` and `*` operators thus it behaves like a pointer. Your list will be destroyed when the last `shared_ptr` object will be destroyed.

Comment: Found a thread elsewhere suggesting that it is not so simple.
https://android.developreference.com/article/13447477/Qt+shared_ptr+signal+with+QThreadPool

Comment: Interesting thread about QSharedPointer: https://forum.qt.io/topic/6148/qsharedpointer-userdatatype-as-signal-slot-parameters/15 with exemple https://forum.qt.io/topic/65422/qsharedpointer-qregistermetatype-gdb-and-slots .

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

I would use `const QList<t> &list` as a signal argument, instead of a pointer. This way there is no need to create a new object, nor to delete it.

## Example

Consider the following example I have prepared for you, in order to demonstrate this approach:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "foo.h"
#include "moo.h"
#include "boo.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    Foo foo;
    Boo boo;
    Moo moo;

    QObject::connect(&foo, &Foo::dataReady, &boo, &Boo::boo);
    QObject::connect(&foo, &Foo::dataReady, &moo, &Moo::moo);

    foo.foo();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**foo.h**

```
#include <QObject>

class Foo: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Foo(QObject *parent = nullptr): QObject(parent) {

    }

    void foo() {
        QList<int> list;

        list.append(77);
        list.append(13);
        list.append(10);

        emit dataReady(list);
    }

signals:
    void dataReady(const QList<int> &list);
};
```

**boo.h**

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

class Boo: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Boo(QObject *parent = nullptr): QObject(parent) {
    }

public slots:
    void boo(const QList<int> &list) {
        qDebug() << "from boo: " << list;
    }
};
```

**moo.h**

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

class Moo: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Moo(QObject *parent = nullptr): QObject(parent) {
    }

public slots:
    void moo(const QList<int> &list) {
        qDebug() << "from moo: " << list;
    }
};
```

## Result

The execution of the example produces the following result:

```
from boo:  (77, 13, 10)
from moo:  (77, 13, 10)
```

Comment: Nice test case.  Will at least work in a single thread, but I fear there would be issues multiple threads.   I will have to look into it.

Comment: @le_top, I use it without problems with multiple threads in a communication application.

Comment: That's recomforting ;-).  I'll test it in my app.

Comment: @le_top, I am looking forward to know the results.

Comment: Unfortunately this optimisation has been stalled so I can not confirm it yet.

Comment: @le_top Then you might just rely on the results of my test (which could be checked by anyone), and consider accepting it as an answer and/or upvoting it.